# How to generate web push vapid keys in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules, web-push

I installed web push :

```
npm i -S web-push
```

Then when I try to generate vapid keys typing this command it throws an error :

```
./node_modules/.bin/web-push generate-vapid-keys
```

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I generate webpush vapid keys in node js ?

Comment: try `node ./node_modules/.bin/web-push generate-vapid-keys`?

Comment: @OlivierKrull I did and it throws syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the error by using `\` instead of `/`

```
.\node_modules\.bin\web-push generate-vapid-keys
```

Answer (score 4):

You can generate the `vapid-keys` with this command:

```
npx web-push generate-vapid-keys [--json]
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push